# How can I manage working hours in Java?

Tags: java, date

I want to ask if someone knows any API or something similar that allows me to manage concrete parts of day (for example working hours)

My problem is that I have to manage times in the next context:

imagine I am working in a company which working hours is "8am-2pm" and "3pm-6pm" and with a daylight saving time from "8am to 2pm". I want to know if a concrete moment of a concrete date is a laboral moment or if it isn't.

For example if I have the mentioned calendar, and I ask the API if the "13th august 2012 at 9pm" is a working moment it has to check it and return a correct answer (false in this case) and if I ask if the "13th august 2012 at 9am" is a working moment it has to return "true"

Other important thing related. I have to calculate intervals between two dates with the mentioned calendar. For example, if i set begin time as "today at 5pm" and end time "tomorrow at 10am" it has to return 3 hours (or its equivalent in seconds or milliseconds) because it is the correct time period passed between the begin date and the end date in this calendar.

It also has to work with holidays (particular of each country). I found an API call "JollyTime" but, although it works with holidays, it does not support the working hours...

Any idea?

Comment: I'd check out Joda Time (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), especially it's period & duration capabilities. As to things like day light savings & holidays, you'reobably going to have to provide your own API forint to meaningful & accurate

Comment: @MadProgrammer fyi, "its" has no apostrophe when it means "belongs to it"

Comment: I guess for the special requirements you will have to do the implementation by yourself...

Comment: ok, thanks all...if i have no alternative i will create the implementation by myself!

Comment: @boheman @ 3am, on iPad, one tends not to take notice of these things ;P

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `with a daylight saving time from "8am to 2pm"`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The Joda-Time library is now in maintenance-mode, its principal author Stephen Colebourne having gone on to lead JSR 310 that defines the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

---

A good database with sophisticated support for date-times may be of assistance here. One such database is [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), with good date-time [data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) and [commands ("functions")](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework may help as well. The [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class and its parent classes define a span of time between a pair of start & stop date-times. They offer methods for comparison such as: contains, overlaps, isBefore, is After.

Here's some example code to get you started, using Joda-Time 2.3 with Java 7.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

List<Interval> workIntervalsFor13Aug2012 = new ArrayList<Interval>( 2 );
DateTime start, stop;
Interval interval;

start = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 8, 0, 0, timeZone );
stop = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 14, 0, 0, timeZone );
interval = new org.joda.time.Interval( start, stop );
workIntervalsFor13Aug2012.add( interval );

start = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 15, 0, 0, timeZone );
stop = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 18, 0, 0, timeZone );
interval = new org.joda.time.Interval( start, stop );
workIntervalsFor13Aug2012.add( interval );

// Check a date-time against those work intervals.
DateTime test09 = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 9, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime test21 = new DateTime( 2012, 8, 13, 21, 0, 0, timeZone );

// You should write a "dateTimeIsInWorkingInterval" method that performs this loop.
Boolean hit = false;
for ( Interval nthInterval : workIntervalsFor13Aug2012 ) {
    if( nthInterval.contains( test09 )) {
        hit = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( hit ) {
    System.out.println( "This date-time: " + test09 + " occurs during a work interval.");
} else {
    System.out.println( "This date-time: " + test09 + " occurs outside a work interval.");
}

hit = false;
for ( Interval nthInterval : workIntervalsFor13Aug2012 ) {
    if( nthInterval.contains( test21 )) {
        hit = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( hit ) {
    System.out.println( "This date-time: " + test21 + " occurs during a work interval.");
} else {
    System.out.println( "This date-time: " + test21 + " occurs outside a work interval.");
}
```

When run…

```
This date-time: 2012-08-13T09:00:00.000+02:00 occurs during a work interval.
This date-time: 2012-08-13T21:00:00.000+02:00 occurs outside a work interval.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JODA Time library.  I know it has intervals and might be just what you need.

Comment: The intervals in joda time are NOT what he needs.  He's looking for intervals during working hours only.  Ie. with 1 hour left in the working day to 1 hour into the next working day would be a 2 hour interval, not 16 (or whatever it would be chronologically).  But i do agree that Joda-Time is the best library for doing any date / time calculations.  Java's built in date/time handling is really bad.

Comment: @Matt I disagree. [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) and its parent [ReadableInterval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInterval.html) seem to be just the ticket. An interval represents the span between a pair of stop and start moments. An interval offers comparison methods: contains, overlaps, isBefore, is After. What do you see as a mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simple solution to calculate working hours between two dates. Starting from this point of view may help you achieve your task.

Here is the class that calculates working time as minutes or miliseconds.

```
public class WorkingTime {

private static final long ONE_SECOND_AS_MILISECONDS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

private Integer startHour;
private Integer endHour;
private Integer startMinute;
private Integer endMinute;

public WorkingTime(int startHour, int endHour) {
    this(startHour, 0, endHour, 0);
}

public WorkingTime(Integer startHour, Integer startMinute, 
        Integer endHour, Integer endMinute) {
    super();
    this.startHour = startHour;
    this.endHour = endHour;
    this.startMinute = startMinute;
    this.endMinute = endMinute;
}

... getters and setters

public long calculateWorkingAsMilis(Date date1, Date date2) {
    return ONE_SECOND_AS_MILISECONDS * calculateWorkingSeconds(date1, date2);
}

public long calculateWorkingSeconds(Date date1, Date date2) {
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);
    setWorkingCalendar(cal1);

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);
    setWorkingCalendar(cal2);

    long day1 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
    long day2 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(cal2.getTimeInMillis());
    long daydiff = day2 - day1;
    long weekendDiff = (daydiff / 7); // get number of weekends
    if (isLeakWeekend(cal1, cal2))
        weekendDiff++;

    long dailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes = getDailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes();
    long secondsToBeDecrementedAsNonWorkingHours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((24 * 60 - dailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes), TimeUnit.MINUTES); // seconds that are not in interval of working hours
    long secondsToBeDecrementedAsWorkingHoursForWeekends = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(dailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes * 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // weekend is not working days, they need to be decremented

    long dayDiffAsSeconds = daydiff * secondsToBeDecrementedAsNonWorkingHours;
    dayDiffAsSeconds += (weekendDiff * secondsToBeDecrementedAsWorkingHoursForWeekends); 

    long workDiffSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(
            cal2.getTimeInMillis() - cal1.getTimeInMillis(),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - dayDiffAsSeconds; 
    return workDiffSeconds;
}

private boolean isLeakWeekend(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
    if (cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) > cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))
        return true;
    return false;
}

private long getDailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes() {
    return (getEndHour() * 60 + getEndMinute()) - (getStartHour() * 60 + getStartMinute());
}

private Calendar setWorkingCalendar(Calendar cal) {
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1);
        resetWorkingHourAndSeconds(cal);
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 2);
        resetWorkingHourAndSeconds(cal);
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > endHour || (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == endHour && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > endMinute)) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endHour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endMinute);
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < startHour || (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == startHour && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < startMinute)) {
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinute);
    }
    return cal;
}
private Calendar resetWorkingHourAndSeconds(Calendar cal) {
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal;
}
```

}

And here is the usage

```
// create an instance (working hours from 08:30 to 17:30)
WorkingTime workingTime = new WorkingTime(8, 30, 17, 30);
long durationAsMilis = workingTime.calculateWorkingAsMilis(date1, date2);
```

Hope that helps

Tuncay Senturk

Comment: Hi! What does getDailyWorkingTimeAsMinutes() method?