# Java calculate time by adding specific number of hours, but consider only working hours and non weekend days

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, weekday

For example I have `sentTime` as an input (25 May 2021 02:00:00 PM) and I need to add `reviewTime` (10 hours) and calculate `releasingTime` (considering only working hours(9am-5pm) and non weekend days)

`25 May 2021 02:00:00 PM` + `10 hours` would be `26 May 2021 04:00:00 PM`

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us your effort.

Comment: Yes, that’s possible. It has also been asked and answered before, so please try your search engine.

Comment: actually I tried, haven't found anything yet on Java

Comment: Similar Question: [*How can I manage working hours in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11934029/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque I appreciate your help, but that questions is a little different, In my case I need to add time, considering only working hours

Comment: @BasilBourque you've sent link to my question

Comment: @ihorko112 (a) Whoops, too many windows open. (b) I have yet to find a satisfying Answer on any similar Questions.

Comment: @OleV.V. I know Stack Overflow has seen similar Questions posted, but I have not seen any with good Answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a function in java or how can i generate a due date considering a work schedule from a initial date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623362/is-there-a-function-in-java-or-how-can-i-generate-a-due-date-considering-a-work)

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

I do not know of any easy way to do this. The *java.time* classes have all the parts needed, but you would have to build up some code to do the calculations.

Be aware that you must account for time zone. On some dates, you will encounter anomalies such as days being 23 or 25 hours long, the clock skipping ahead or dropping behind. One example of such anomalies is [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), but that is not the only cause. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for redefining the time-keeping of their jurisdictions for varied reasons.

Here is a brief example to get you started, if you choose to go this route.

Besides the *java.time* classes built into Java, this code also leverages the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library which adds functionality to *java.time*. We need that library for two classes here:

- A [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) for finding the [next working day](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay()) (skipping Saturday-Sunday). See [tutorial on temporal adjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/adjusters.html). Tip: You may want to consider implementing a `TemporalAdjuster` on your own as part of a real solution — but I'm not sure, just an idea I have not thought through.
- [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class to track a pair of moments as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). Not required here, but might be useful in further work.

```java
Duration work = Duration.ofHours( 10 );

LocalTime shiftStart = LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 );
LocalTime shiftEnd = LocalTime.of( 17 , 0 );

ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime startOfWork = ZonedDateTime.of( 2021 , 5 , 25 , 14 , 0 , 0 , 0 , z );

// Calculate how much time left in the day to work.
ZonedDateTime endOfDayOne = startOfWork.with( shiftEnd );
Duration untilEndOfDayOne = Duration.between( startOfWork , endOfDayOne );
Duration remainingWork = work.minus( untilEndOfDayOne );

// Determine next work-day.
// Add ThreeTen-Extra library to your project to access the `TemporalAdjuster` for `nextWorkingDay()`.
LocalDate nextWorkDay = endOfDayOne.toLocalDate().with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() );
ZonedDateTime startOfNextWorkingDay = ZonedDateTime.of( nextWorkDay , shiftStart , z );
ZonedDateTime endOfWork = startOfNextWorkingDay.plus( remainingWork );

org.threeten.extra.Interval workInterval =
        org.threeten.extra.Interval.of(
                startOfWork.toInstant() ,
                endOfWork.toInstant()
        );
```

Dump to console. By default, *java.time* generates text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

```java
System.out.println( "startOfWork = " + startOfWork );
System.out.println( "work = " + work );  
System.out.println( "endOfWork = " + endOfWork );
System.out.println( "workInterval = " + workInterval );
```

When run.

```
startOfWork = 2021-05-25T14:00-05:00[America/Chicago]
work = PT10H
endOfWork = 2021-05-26T16:00-05:00[America/Chicago]
workInterval = 2021-05-25T19:00:00Z/2021-05-26T21:00:00Z
```

## Project management software

[Project Management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management_software) is built to do this very job: Calculate elapsed time for various tasks restricted by working hours and working days. One possible solution is trying to leverage such a library for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sentTime` is of type `java.util.Date`, you can may be use the following code that utilizes Java 8's `java.time.LocalDateTime`

```
int reviewTime = 10;
List<DayOfWeek> weekends = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
LocalDateTime start = sentTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
final int workingHoursStart = 9;
final int workingHoursEnd = 17;
int hoursReviewed = 0;

while(reviewTime > hoursReviewed){
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = start.getDayOfWeek();
    if(weekends.contains(dayOfWeek) || start.getHour() < workingHoursStart || start.getHour() > workingHoursEnd){
        start = start.plusHours(1);
        continue;
    }
    start = start.plusHours(1);
    hoursReviewed++;
}
```

Your resultant `releasingTime` time would be in the `start` object after the loop finishes iterating.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but something not quite right here, it gives me 2021-05-26T15:00 but should be 2021-05-26T16:00, and also if input for ex: 25 May 2021 02:30:00 PM and reviewTime is 3 hours, it gives me as an output 2021-05-25T17:30 but should be 2021-05-26T09:30

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here, assuming we want a realistic schedule where days vary in length.